# Send request to algolia servers when user stops typing

Tags: algolia

I want to find a way to set a timeout after each character typed by user so it will not make a request to algolia server after each character typed.

so when user types a character it waits 1 second, and if user does not type any other key then send the request to algolia server

something like this:

```
function onUserKeyUp (){
    clearTimeout('TIMEout');

    TIMEout=setTimeout(function() {
        SendRequestToALGOLIA()
    }, 1000);

}
```

do algolia has api for this?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, note that Algolia sends request at every keystroke for **User-experience** reasons: [instant-search experiences are most engaging for users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search), while delaying network requests on user interaction will make visitors feel like the interface is stuttering, resulting in a suboptimal experience for them.

This being said, although Algolia doesn't recommend it, you can build this using their API Clients and `setTimeout`.

- Read an example usage of the API Client you want to use. For example with Algolia's Places API: [Example using an API Client](https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#using-an-api-client)

  - Wrap the code of this example into a function, for example `sendRequestToAlgolia()`
- Define a `setAlgoliaTimeout()` function that uses `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` as [documented on this W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) to trigger that `sendRequestToAlgolia()` function after a delay of your choice
- Follow [MDN's example for keyup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) to define a listener that triggers your `setAlgoliaTimeout()` method when a valid `keyup` events arrives.